# Why do for loops initialize a new value when the iterator is declared with let?

Tags: javascript

In this classic interview question, a new `i` is created for each iteration. This new `i` has closure with the function in `setTimeout` and produces the output `0 1 2 3 4`. I don't understand why a new `i` is initialized when it's declared with `let` but not when it's declared with `var`. That should be impossible since `let` doesn't allow another variable with the same name to be created. Also, since closures are created when a function is defined, shouldn't the anonymous function in `setTimeout` still have closure around the original `i` equal to 0 in the block scope? Thanks.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
//Output: 
//0 
//1
//2
//3
//4
```

Comment: what result did you expect? `0, 0, 0, 0, 0`?

Comment: I am not sure if i understood the paragraph above the code.

But for every iteration, there is a new setTimeout that gets added to 'macrotasks' queue with a different value of 'i' by virtue of block scoping nature of 'let'. 

And once the for loop is done executing, the macrotasks are executed, so each 'i' is different.

Comment: After reading the blog post, I believe I understand. This behavior is specially created for `for` loops with `let` declarations. The binding is dynamically reassigned at runtime and this will not occur with `var` or `const`.

Comment: I don't think it matters that the let variable is block scoped. The anonymous function that setTimeout sends to the Web API has closure with `i` whether its declared with `let` or `var`. If they did not make a special interaction between for loops and let declarations so there's a fresh binding for each iteration, the `async` function would be bound to the wrong value.

Comment: To understand this you need to understand blocks, closures and scopes. I really recommend to read the whole book: "You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures": https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures . There is also a part that explains this case: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#loops--closure

Comment: I think I understand blocks and closures pretty well, which is why the standard explanation didn't make sense. That explanation is good but doesn't mention re-binding. The re-declaration is important, but the asynchronous function only has a fresh binding to the re-declared variable due to the behavior of let declarations within for loops (talked about here https://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html). Closure is formed where the function is defined so without this dynamic re-binding there will be stale closure. I believe my understanding is correct but always open to new info.